# AWS Lambda function throws ClassNotFoundException - LambdaHandler. Current classpath: file:/var/task/

Tags: java, amazon-web-services, spring-boot, aws-lambda, aws-api-gateway

Spring boot application I am deploying as a Lambda on the top of APIGetway - Getting error

```
 Class not found: com.myapp.app.LambdaHandler: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException
java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: com.myapp.app.LambdaHandler. Current classpath: file:/var/task/
```

When the Jar file are getting created, I see there are 3 folder  - BOOT-INF, META-INF, org.

My package are there inside the BOOT_INF -> classes -> com -> myapp -> app -> LambdaHandler

**Deployment doing using - serverless.yml**

**Deployment from Command prompt CLI - serverless deploy**

**StreamLambdaHandler.java**

```
public class StreamLambdaHandler implements RequestStreamHandler {  
  private static SpringBootLambdaContainerHandler<AwsProxyRequest, AwsProxyResponse> handler; 
    static {
        try {
            handler = SpringBootLambdaContainerHandler.getAwsProxyHandler(Application.class);
        } catch (Exception e) {
            // if we fail here. We re-throw the exception to force another cold start
            e.printStackTrace();
            throw new RuntimeException("Could not initialize Spring Boot Application", e);
        }
    }

    @Override
    public void handleRequest(InputStream inputStream, OutputStream outputStream, Context context)
            throws IOException {
        handler.proxyStream(inputStream, outputStream, context);
    } 
}
```

**Application.java**

```
@SpringBootApplication
@Configuration
@EnableAutoConfiguration
public class Application extends SpringBootServletInitializer {
    /**
     * Create required HandlerMapping, to avoid several default HandlerMapping instances being created
     */
    @Bean
    public HandlerMapping handlerMapping() {
        return new RequestMappingHandlerMapping();
    }

    /**
     * Create required HandlerAdapter, to avoid several default HandlerAdapter instances being created
     */
    @Bean
    public HandlerAdapter handlerAdapter() {
        return new RequestMappingHandlerAdapter();
    }
    
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        SpringApplication.run(Application.class, args);
    }
}
```

**My Controller -**

```
@RestController
@EnableWebMvc
@Profile("lambda")
@RequestMapping("/app/v2")
public class ClientInformation {
    @Value("${clientDetails.userName}")
    private String userName;
    
    @Value("${clientDetails.userId}")
    private int userId;
    
    @Value("${clientDetails.userAddress}")
    private String userAddress;
    
    @GetMapping("/")
    public Map<String, Object> getDetails()  {  
        Map<String, Object> rtn = new HashMap<>();
        rtn.put("message", "App is working fine !!!");
        return rtn;
    }
    
    @GetMapping("/information")
    public Map<String, Object> getInformation()  {  
        Map<String, Object> rtn = new HashMap<>();
        rtn.put("name", userName);
        rtn.put("id", userId);
        return rtn;
    }
    
    @GetMapping("/ping")
    public Map<String, Object> getD() {
        Map<String, Object> rtn = new HashMap<>();
        rtn.put("name", "Ping is happening !!!");
        rtn.put("status", "200");
        return rtn;
    }
}
```

**Serverless.yml** -

```
service: myapplication-api
provider:
  name: aws
  runtime: java11
  memorySize: 512
  timeout: 15
 profile: default
  stage: production
package:
  artifact: target/myapp-api-0.0.1-SNAPSHOT-exec.jar

functions:
  catchAllAny:
    handler: index.catchAllAny
    events:
      - httpApi: '*'
  catchAllMethod:
    handler: handler.catchAllMethod
    events:
      - httpApi:
          method: '*'
          path: /any/method
```

**pom.xml**

**May I Know what I am doing wrong ? -**

```html
<project xmlns="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0"
    xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
    xsi:schemaLocation="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0 https://maven.apache.org/xsd/maven-4.0.0.xsd">
    <modelVersion>4.0.0</modelVersion>
    <parent>
        <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-parent</artifactId>
        <version>2.1.1.RELEASE</version>
        <relativePath /> <!-- lookup parent from repository -->
    </parent>
    <groupId>com.myapp.app</groupId>
    <artifactId>myapp-api</artifactId>
    <version>0.0.1-SNAPSHOT</version>
    <name>myapp-api</name>
    <description>Demo project for Spring Boot</description>
    <properties>
        <java.version>1.8</java.version>
    </properties>
    <dependencies>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-actuator</artifactId>
        </dependency>

        <!-- <dependency> <groupId>com.amazonaws</groupId> <artifactId>aws-java-sdk</artifactId> 
            <version>1.11.931</version> </dependency> -->
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-data-mongodb</artifactId>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-security</artifactId>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-web</artifactId>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-mail</artifactId>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-devtools</artifactId>
            <scope>runtime</scope>
            <optional>true</optional>
        </dependency>
        <!-- Spring boot lambda Serverless -->
        <dependency>
            <groupId>com.amazonaws.serverless</groupId>
            <artifactId>aws-serverless-java-container-spring</artifactId>
            <version>1.2</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>com.amazonaws</groupId>
            <artifactId>aws-lambda-java-events</artifactId>
            <version>1.3.0</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>com.amazonaws.serverless</groupId>
            <artifactId>aws-serverless-java-container-springboot2</artifactId>
            <version>1.5.2</version>
        </dependency>
        
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.projectlombok</groupId>
            <artifactId>lombok</artifactId>
            <optional>true</optional>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-test</artifactId>
            <scope>test</scope>
        </dependency>



        <dependency>
            <groupId>net.authorize</groupId>
            <artifactId>anet-java-sdk</artifactId>
            <version>2.0.6</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.security</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-security-test</artifactId>
            <scope>test</scope>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>io.jsonwebtoken</groupId>
            <artifactId>jjwt</artifactId>
            <version>0.9.1</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>io.springfox</groupId>
            <artifactId>springfox-swagger2</artifactId>
            <version>2.9.2</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>io.springfox</groupId>
            <artifactId>springfox-swagger-ui</artifactId>
            <version>2.9.2</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>io.springfox</groupId>
            <artifactId>springfox-bean-validators</artifactId>
            <version>2.9.2</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
            <artifactId>maven-shade-plugin</artifactId>
            <version>3.0.0</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.hibernate.validator</groupId>
            <artifactId>hibernate-validator</artifactId>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>net.logstash.logback</groupId>
            <artifactId>logstash-logback-encoder</artifactId>
            <version>5.2</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.glassfish.jaxb</groupId>
            <artifactId>jaxb-runtime</artifactId>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>com.google.code.gson</groupId>
            <artifactId>gson</artifactId>
            <version>2.8.7</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.apache.poi</groupId>
            <artifactId>poi</artifactId>
            <version>3.15</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>com.amazonaws</groupId>
            <artifactId>aws-java-sdk-s3</artifactId>
            <version>1.12.226</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.apache.poi</groupId>
            <artifactId>poi-ooxml</artifactId>
            <version>3.15</version>
        </dependency>
    </dependencies>

    <build>
        <plugins>
            <plugin>
                <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
                <artifactId>spring-boot-maven-plugin</artifactId>
                <configuration>
                    <classifier>exec</classifier>
                    <executable>false</executable>
                    <excludes>
                        <exclude>
                            <groupId>org.projectlombok</groupId>
                            <artifactId>lombok</artifactId>
                        </exclude>
                    </excludes>
                </configuration>
            </plugin>
        </plugins>

    </build>

</project>
```

Comment: Is there a class named LambdaHandler in package com.myapp.app in your deployed code? I see StreamLambdaHandler without any obvious package.

Comment: handler = SpringBootLambdaContainerHandler.getAwsProxyHandler(Application.class);

Application class are nothing but the main class. 

StreamLambdaHandler.java and Application.java -> Both are belongs to the same package - com.myapp.app

Comment: @jarmod - Can you please let me know what is the issue ?

Answer (score 0):

You need to configure your serverless.yml to specify the full package of StreamLambdaHandler as the handler attribute.

For example, if the class was in com.myapp package. You would need to specify com.myapp.StreamLambdaHandler

You are currently specifying com.myapp.app.LambdaHandler and that is a class that doesn't exist.

Answer (score 0):

In Springboot we have all the @Controller, @Service, annotation. So Lamba is not smart enough to understand this. Until unless we do some hacks. But that is not advisable by Amazon Web Services. What we can do -

We can make a use of Spring cloud function. Here is the link -

- https://www.baeldung.com/spring-cloud-function
- https://spring.io/projects/spring-cloud-function
- https://github.com/spring-cloud/spring-cloud-function/tree/main/spring-cloud-function-samples/function-sample-aws

Please put thumbs up, if you like this information.

Answer (score 0):

Add below to the `pom.xml` file:

```xml
<build>
    <plugins>
        <plugin>
            <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
            <artifactId>maven-deploy-plugin</artifactId>
            <configuration>
                <skip>true</skip>
            </configuration>
        </plugin>
        <plugin>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-maven-plugin</artifactId>
            <dependencies>
                <dependency>
                    <groupId>org.springframework.boot.experimental</groupId>
                    <artifactId>spring-boot-thin-layout</artifactId>
                    <version>1.0.28.RELEASE</version>  // You may need to update this version according to your Java & Spring Boot version
                </dependency>
            </dependencies>
        </plugin>
        <plugin>
            <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
            <artifactId>maven-shade-plugin</artifactId>
            <configuration>
                <createDependencyReducedPom>false</createDependencyReducedPom>
                <shadedArtifactAttached>true</shadedArtifactAttached>
                <shadedClassifierName>aws</shadedClassifierName>
            </configuration>
        </plugin>
    </plugins>
</build>
```