# Class not found: com.app.handler.AsynchronousLambdaHandler: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException, Current classpath: file:/var/task/

Tags: java, amazon-web-services, spring-boot, aws-lambda, serverless-framework

I have developed a spring boot REST API, trying to deploy it using serverless framework as a Lambda on top of API Gateway, and encountered the following the error

```
Class not found: com.app.handler.AsynchronousLambdaHandler: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException
java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: com.app.handler.AsynchronousLambdaHandler. Current classpath: file:/var/task/
```

I am using ***Spring Boot version 2.7.10***, ***java version 11***, ***maven*** as a build tool, and ***serverless*** as a deployment tool to deploy the application in AWS.

The handler class is available at `BOOT-INF/classes/com/app/handler/AsynchronousLambdaHandler.class` post-packing the application as a `.jar` file.

***serverless.yml***

```
service: integration-service

provider:
    name: aws
    region: us-east-1
    stage: ${opt:stage, 'dev'}

functions:
    "integration-service":
        handler: com.app.handler.AsynchronousLambdaHandler::handleRequest
        name: ${opt:stage, 'dev'}-integration-service
        runtime: java11
        memorySize: 512
        events:
            -   http: ANY /{proxy+}
```

***pom.xml***

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<project xmlns="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
         xsi:schemaLocation="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0 https://maven.apache.org/xsd/maven-4.0.0.xsd">
    <modelVersion>4.0.0</modelVersion>
    <parent>
        <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-parent</artifactId>
        <version>2.7.10</version>
        <relativePath/> <!-- lookup parent from repository -->
    </parent>
    <groupId>com.app</groupId>
    <artifactId>integration-service</artifactId>
    <version>1.0.0</version>
    <name>integration-service</name>
    <description>Integration Service</description>
    <properties>
        <java.version>11</java.version>
    </properties>
    <dependencies>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-web</artifactId>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-data-jpa</artifactId>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>com.amazonaws.serverless</groupId>
            <artifactId>aws-serverless-java-container-springboot2</artifactId>
            <version>1.9.2</version>
        </dependency>
    </dependencies>
    <build>
        <plugins>
            <plugin>
                <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
                <artifactId>spring-boot-maven-plugin</artifactId>
                <configuration>
                    <finalName>${project.artifactId}</finalName>
                </configuration>
            </plugin>
            <plugin>
                <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
                <artifactId>maven-shade-plugin</artifactId>
                <version>3.2.4</version>
                <configuration>
                    <createDependencyReducedPom>false</createDependencyReducedPom>
                </configuration>
                <executions>
                    <execution>
                        <phase>package</phase>
                        <goals>
                            <goal>shade</goal>
                        </goals>
                    </execution>
                </executions>
            </plugin>
        </plugins>
    </build>
</project>
```

AsynchronousLambdaHandler.java

```
package com.app.handler;

import com.amazonaws.serverless.exceptions.ContainerInitializationException;
import com.amazonaws.serverless.proxy.model.*;
import com.amazonaws.serverless.proxy.spring.*;
import com.amazonaws.services.lambda.runtime.*;
import com.app.IntegrationServiceApplication;

public class AsynchronousLambdaHandler implements RequestHandler<AwsProxyRequest, AwsProxyResponse> {
    private SpringBootLambdaContainerHandler<AwsProxyRequest, AwsProxyResponse> handler;

    public AsynchronousLambdaHandler() throws ContainerInitializationException {
        handler = (SpringBootLambdaContainerHandler<AwsProxyRequest, AwsProxyResponse>) new SpringBootProxyHandlerBuilder()
                .springBootApplication(IntegrationServiceApplication.class)
                .asyncInit()
                .buildAndInitialize();
    }

    @Override
    public AwsProxyResponse handleRequest(AwsProxyRequest input, Context context) {
        return handler.proxy(input, context);
    }
}
```

I have also explored a lot of options including this one ([AWS Lambda function throws ClassNotFoundException - LambdaHandler. Current classpath: file:/var/task/](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/72535951/aws-lambda-function-throws-classnotfoundexception-lambdahandler-current-class)) but no luck so far.

### Edit:

Updated the pom.xml to remove maven plugins to simplyfy the problem.

***pom.xml (updated)***

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<project xmlns="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
         xsi:schemaLocation="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0 https://maven.apache.org/xsd/maven-4.0.0.xsd">
    <modelVersion>4.0.0</modelVersion>
    <parent>
        <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-parent</artifactId>
        <version>2.7.10</version>
        <relativePath/> <!-- lookup parent from repository -->
    </parent>
    <groupId>com.app</groupId>
    <artifactId>integration-service</artifactId>
    <version>1.0.0</version>
    <name>integration-service</name>
    <description>Integration Service</description>
    <properties>
        <java.version>11</java.version>
    </properties>
    <dependencies>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-web</artifactId>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-data-jpa</artifactId>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>com.amazonaws.serverless</groupId>
            <artifactId>aws-serverless-java-container-springboot2</artifactId>
            <version>1.9.2</version>
        </dependency>
    </dependencies>
    <build>
        <finalName>${artifactId}</finalName>
    </build>
</project>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I finally found the solution after going through a lot of blogs, docs, and different web pages. As everyone is suggesting, I have added the following code in pom.xml but the most important point that folks missed highlighting is ***instead of deploying the normal `.jar` file deploy your `-aws.jar` file***.

```
<plugin>
    <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
    <artifactId>maven-shade-plugin</artifactId>
    <version>3.4.0</version>
    <configuration>
        <createDependencyReducedPom>false</createDependencyReducedPom>
        <shadedArtifactAttached>true</shadedArtifactAttached>
        <shadedClassifierName>aws</shadedClassifierName>
    </configuration>
    <executions>
        <execution>
            <phase>package</phase>
            <goals>
                <goal>shade</goal>
            </goals>
            <configuration>
                <artifactSet>
                    <excludes>
                        <exclude>org.apache.tomcat.embed:*</exclude>
                    </excludes>
                </artifactSet>
            </configuration>
        </execution>
    </executions>
</plugin>
```